# Why was this music question locked after I flagged it, but my flag was declined?

Tags: discussion, support, identification-questions, flagging

[What is the song playing in My Hero Academia season 2 episode 25 at 10:00?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/what-is-the-song-playing-in-my-hero-academia-season-2-episode-25-at-1000)

I just noticed it was bumped, so I thought I'd do a good deed and report it. I said

> music sooooo close?

As a reward for my effort, I got

> declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see What is Flagging?

Explain please.

Now I wanna flag this: [What's the song playing in episode 25 in the middle of Akagi vs Washizu match?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/47206/whats-the-song-playing-in-episode-25-in-the-middle-of-akagi-vs-washizu-match) But I might

## declined

again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not the moderator who declined the flag, but as a mod, I would do the same by declining the flag for the same reason.

Basically, you are *misusing the mod flag* when there is already a standard flag to close the question: flag - needs improvement - A community-specific reason - Identification reasons (*all flags under **"needs improvement"** will put the question in the [close votes review queue](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/close)*).

The process of closing music ID questions does not really need a mod, and moreover, it is not that critical that a mod needs to handle it quickly. However, by using a mod flag, the standard process of getting it to the close votes review queue (which then can be handled by the community and also the mods) is bypassed and go straight to the mod-only flag queue, which is unnecessary.

Please just use the standard flag from now on, and let the community handle it.

Comment: Oh ok I really had no idea flags could go that deep like A > B > C > D. Perfectly fair. Thanks for the explanation Andrew. Ok just now I flagged the Akagi question. Let's see how it goes...